# Resque is calling a method on the class when really it should be called on a record, thus producing a no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I call this method in the console:

```
pry(main)> Resque.enqueue(GameMetrics, 142)
=> true
```

Here is the error on the Resque front-end in Game Metrics Queue's failed jobs tab after performing the above:

[image]

Here is my perform method(within the job folder):

```
class GameMetrics
  @queue = :game_metrics

  def self.perform(game_id)
    game = Game.find(game_id)
    if game.data_recorded? == false && game.number == 1 && game.user.is_admin? == false
      game.answered_game_questions.includes(:question).each do |game_question|
        company_question = CompanyQuestion.find_or_create_by(company: game.company, question: game_question.question)
        company_question.increment(:freq_100_credit_gained) if game_question.change_in_earnings == 100
        company_question.increment(:freq_over_49_lost_of_total_poss_loss) if game_question.percentage_points_lost > 49
        company_question.increment(:freq_over_66_lost_of_total_poss_loss) if game_question.percentage_points_lost > 66
        company_question.increment(:freq_answered)
        company_question.save
      end
    end
    game.update(data_recorded?: true)
  end
end
```

There is indeed a game with ID 142 so what could be the issue here? Thank you!!
I'm using rails 4.2 and resque 1.22.0

Comment: Is `data_recorded?` an instance method of Game?

Comment: Yes , figured out the mistake, will answer below -thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of head banging I figured out that I just needed to restart my

```
rake QUEUE=* environment resque:work
```

task to load up the new environment/working code.

I had thought of restarting the local redis server but forgot about the rake task.

TL;DR restart all your shit when you change code and don't understand why shit doesn't work

Hope this helps someone!